# I'm getting same output of "Nodding" in first if else condition instead of "Smiling". Could anyone tell me what can I do to fix it?

Tags: python

I'm getting same output of "Nodding" in first if else condition instead of "Smiling". Could anyone tell me what can I do to fix it?

```
mood = ('happy', 'sad', 'neutral', 'angry', 'joy', 'calm')
content = ('positive', 'negative', 'unsure')

i = input('Enter sentence: ')
str = i.split(' ')
for m in str:
    for c in str:
        if m == mood[0] and c == content[0]:
            print("Smiling")
            exit()
        elif m == mood[0] and c == content[2]:
            print("Nodding")
            exit()
        elif  m == mood[1]:
            print("Frowning")
            exit()
        elif m == mood[2] and content[0] or content[1]:
            print("Nodding")
            exit()
        elif m == mood[2] and content[2]:
            print("Blinking")
        else:
            exit()
```

Output:

```
Enter sentence: i am happy and positive
Nodding
```

I should be getting "Smiling" for the above output instead of "Nodding".

Comment: Can you give a sample input, the actual output and the expected output ? Please [edit] your post for that, not in the comment section

Comment: anecdotally, this seems like a good case for a dictionary

Comment: Please read about how to provide a [mre]. Your program takes input from the user so it's hard for us to know how to run it. It is better to post an example of your code with hard-coded values that we can just copy-paste and run

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: I said [edit] your post, NOT in the comment section, so you can write it properly

Comment: What do you meant by `m == mood[2] and content[0] or content[1]` and `m == mood[2] and content[2]` condition ? There are strange and surely wrong

Comment: As i said i'm a newbie. How can i catch tuple values in a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The condition `m == mood[2] and content[0] or content[1]` doesn't do what you want, you forgot the `c` comparison, it should be

```
elif m == mood[2] and c in (content[0], content[1])

elif m == mood[2] and c == content[2]
```

---

But instead of iterating on the content with 2 for loops, you could store the data in a `dict` where

- the `key` is a `tuple` of the keywords to find
- the `value` is what to print

Then if all keywords of a pair are found in the given sentence, then print the value

```
humors = {
    ('happy', 'positive'): 'Smiling',
    ('happy', 'unsure'): 'Nodding',
    ('sad',): 'Frowning',
    ('neutral', 'positive'): 'Nodding',
    ('neutral', 'negative'): 'Nodding',
    ('neutral', 'unsure'): 'Blinking',
}

content = input('Enter sentence: ')
for keywords, action in humors.items():
    if all(keyword in content for keyword in keywords):
        print(action)
        break
```

Comment: Oh right. I'll try this. Thank you for your response. :)